# Show from Most Recent Post to the Oldest one in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to show the **Most Recent Post** in the top and sort the displaying post order to most recent to the oldest.

I have the following code.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
   <div class="blog-posts">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pre-post-wrapper">
      <article data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-offset="100" class="blog-post-wrapper">


        <div class="post-img">
          <?php $thumb = null; ?>
          <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
              <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt=""></a>
          <?php else: ?>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/framework/assets/images/default.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <div class="bp-img-arrow">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 14); ?></a></h2>
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()), 45); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" class="post-link">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="bp-details">
              <div class="bp-comment">
                <?php $c_count =get_comments_number(); ?>
                <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $c_count ?> Comments</span>
              </div>
              <div class="bp-time">
                <?php if(get_field('read_time')){
                        $read_time = get_field('read_time').'Minutes';?>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $read_time ?></span>
                      <?php
                       }else{
                        // $read_time = 'Not Defined';
                      } ?>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
  </div>
 </div>
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="pagination-wrapper">
   <?php pagination(); ?>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
   <h5>No Posts found.</h5>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code shows all the posts, but the problem is it shuffles the posts somehow. I can't see the most recent post in the very top as well as not in the bottom. It's somewhere in the middle. How can I sort the order of displaying the posts?

Comment: There should some query before the 1st line you posted or check function for a hook in `pre_get_post`

Comment: Since I am accessing the blog post I didn't use `WP_Query()` for this, this works fine. But I want them to be sorted as In mentioned

Comment: By default wordpress does sort by most recent. Are you sure your theme doesn't have option where you can set that. Other option try echo out the query it ran. For further clue. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4818/15420

Comment: This should be the default behavior of WordPress. Can you how exactly the post got shuffled? The code you extracted here, is this from index.php?

Comment: Where is you `query` code ?

Comment: @josephting Yes I have developed my own theme and this code is from twentyfifteen and I made some changes in html but not in the looping

Comment: @SudharshanNair As I mentioned in the comment this is blog post loop, So i don't need to have a query here

Comment: Can you add blog post code too in your question?

Comment: @SudharshanNair Do you mean the html?

Comment: What ever the code that is inside that file

Comment: @SudharshanNair I think it's not necessary, but In added to the question. Please checkout

Comment: @Ramesh As suggested by @cjmling , adding `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;` right before `if (have_posts())` will show you the query that resulted in your posts result. That may help to find out what went wrong.

Comment: do you have any file inside with name `blog-post-list.php`

Comment: @SudharshanNair added the code to the question

Comment: Please  do that as suggested by @josephting. It will show you what query is being executed

Comment: @josephting I tried it sir, but nothing get printed in my screen.

Comment: Are you sure, that the code you are checking is correct? Add `exit;` So that you know code is loaded from that file

Comment: @SudharshanNair Yes I am

Comment: @Ramesh If you added that to index.php and nothing was displayed, it indicates that another template is being used instead. Do `echo get_page_template();` in header.php and see which template file is being used. If the template file being shown does not exist in your theme, only then it will default to index.php.

Comment: @josephting I had super cache enabled, that's why I couldn't read the query. Now I disabled and this is the query that I am getting printed `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: @Ramesh Nothing wrong with the SQL as it is the default behavior of Wordpress where post_date is sorted in descending order. Can you share more details about how the posts get shuffled?

Comment: @josephting Now I added two posts `test` and `hello`. You can see it here https://www.domedia.lk/blog/ . Posts added on SEPTEMBER 7, 2018 and SEPTEMBER 17, 2018 are in the top, then only my latest posts got loaded. You can see the post date in single page in the title bar

Comment: @Ramesh Okay, with limited visibility of your code, I can only make assumptions. If that's the case, it's highly likely that somewhere else has injected those 2 posts into your page. Either directly to the loop or just located somewhere else. There are a lot of ways to do that. You will have to ask the original developer if you weren't in charge of putting that in.

Comment: @josephting This sounds great. I exported and imported the blogs from the client's old website. That may be issue. Thank you for your patience and time sir :-)

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress codex, you can find all your thinking bro:

```
    <?php 
    // the query
    $all_posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 
    'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
    <?php if ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ul>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
   </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I want all the posts to be displayed but sorted from the recent to older. The above answer provides the way to access the recent posts

Comment: I edited my code you can check, hope that will helps you!

Comment: Still I have the problem, as @josephting mentioned in the comment section there's a problem in post configuration. Thank you for your consideration sir

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $query = new WP_Query(
      array(
         'post_type'=>'post',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'orderby' => 'publish_date',
         'order' => 'DESC',
         'posts_per_page' => -1

      )
   );
?>
```

Hope, this will help. Thanks.